# nodejs Browserify node-xmpp bundle error: cannot find module dns

Tags: node.js, browserify

I have created a JS bundle file from [node-xmpp](https://github.com/astro/node-xmpp) using [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) but when I load my website I get the following error in the Google Chrome Javascript console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'dns'
```

I tried installing the [browser-request](https://github.com/iriscouch/browser-request) node package using `npm install -g browser-request` and to rebuild the JS bundle but I still get the same error.

What do I need to include/install in order to get rid of this error?

Note: I am using a debian server with the latest version of nodejs and [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an commit that has not been added to the latest build yet that solved my problem.

https://github.com/dodo/node-xmpp/commit/a49e7be0e43885060aaf26c2772b41c618624f12

I've added a screenshot containing the changes for if the link dies:
[image]